# Reputation change due to documentation should be removed from the Help Center

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, documentation, reputation, help-center

Reputation change due to documentation should be removed or comment from the [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) page in the Help Center:

> example you contributed to is voted up: +5
>
> proposed change is approved: +2
>
> first time an answer that cites documentation you contributed to is upvoted: +5

Comment: I think the reputation page should state that you now can earn reputation on documentation related action

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. The original title made it look like you want to remove the earned reputation *itself*.

Comment: They should probably revert it back to [the original](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) which is used all over the network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, ok.

I wanted to make a few other changes there anyway - gettin' tired of seeing folks assuming they can't participate here without reputation.

Page is now the same on SO as it is everywhere else.

Comment: You might want to look at the links in the "So what is reputation?" paragraph. I'm seeing unrendered markdown for the last two.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew - fixed. Mixing HTML and markdown sucks.